# Lua - Как получить наименьшее значение в таблице

Tags: lua, table, min

**Суть вопроса:**
У меня есть массив: **{1.4426,1.5528,5.2444,2.3385}***(он будет каждый раз разным)*, как получить **НАИМЕНЬШЕЕ** значение из этого массива?
***math.min() не подходит.***

Comment: просто напиши код

Comment: `math.min() не подходит` - попробуй `math.min(table.unpack(t))`